"Edit columns in the form" does not work with imported lists
I am working in SharePoint Online. I have imported several lists from another site collection using the following process:

Open Site Contents and click New | List.
From the Create a list dialog, click "From existing list".
Choose a library in another site collection, "Requirements".

Now, Requirements has lookup columns to several other lists: Projects, Environments, Flows, etc. So without even prompting me, SharePoint imported all of these related lists as well. That's a good thing, and an improvement over SP 2013 and other on-premises versions. Lookup columns were always a hassle, you had to drop the columns and readd them in the new site. So all of my lists were brought in for me. All good.
When I edit the properties of a document in Requirements, everything seems to work fine. But when I try to add or edit an item in Projects, only the Title field is shown in the Edit panel. There are a dozen columns in this list. When I click New and click "Edit columns in the form", the ONLY visible column is Title.
The same is true for all the lookup lists that were imported for me. If I add a NEW column to my Projects list, it appears in the form and in the "Edit columns in the form" panel. Does this mean I need to delete and readd every single column in my list?

Are these columns present in the list settings?
If yes:
Check and Adjust Form Column Settings:

Go to the List Settings of your Projects list.
Under Content Types, click on the content type that is being used for items in the list (e.g., "Item").
Click on Column settings and ensure that the missing columns are set to be Visible in the list forms (New/Edit/Display).

If no:
what happens, when you try to add a column with exactly the same name? What will be its internal name?

That sent me down the right path. Only "Title" was shown under Item when I looked at Content Types. I clicked "Add from existing site or list columns" and it showed me all the missing columns under "List Columns". Once I added them to the Content Type, they show up in the form. Makes perfect sense now, but not sure why importing the list doesn't recreate the Content Type.
